# Should I break my data into smaller pieces?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have an excel sheet with over 1,000,000 rows that I need to perform some vlookups/countif statements.  Should I run my VB macros on a single sheet with all the data, or will splitting the data into 50,000 increments on separate sheets then running the macro on each sheet create a significant time savings?  Is there an equation out there that can help me make this decision?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the VB I plan to use, (Though I am more looking for a general answer, if there is one, that I can apply when I deal with these large db extractions in excel):

```
Sub Find_Space_then_Compare()
'
' Finds the Space in the Key, Extracts Character after, and looks for match 
in Sample2 sheet

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-1],FIND("" "",RC[-1])+1,256)"
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B100")
Range("B2:B100").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sample2!R81C3:R121C3,1)"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C100")
Range("C2:C100").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what `vlookup` and `countif` have to do with macros. But it is certainly a good idea not to have more than a million formulas in all these cells with calculation set to automatic (if you have that option). Now, getting to your question of speed comparison / best practices it would seem to me that this question is slightly off-topic for SO and is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Having said that I'd just go ahead and run the macro on either version and get the internal time to measure the difference: test it yourself.

Comment: The macros I am running involve vlookups', and countif's.  I mention this because if the my function was just a =left([field],2)  then the time to run even for a million rows in short enough that splitting the data would not be worth my effort.  However the =vlookup can take multiple minutes to run.  And thank you for your input.

Comment: @Ralph a question that contains no working code to review has nothing to do on [codereview.se], and has a lifespan measured in seconds before a hammer hits it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The author of this post mentions working code. I am sure that he/she is just a minute away from updating the above post and including the code he/she has written.

Comment: If you have working code that's just slow to execute but otherwise gets the job done, then yeah, *present it* to reviewers on [codereview.se]. Please read [CR's help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you post. Reviewers will tell you to read your data into an array and work in memory instead of directly with the worksheet, and they'll comment on every single aspect of the code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really terrible such a huge database, now I would like to suggest split your database into few pieces and apply the formula. Below is the example for 2 pieces.

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,data1,2,FALSE))),VLOOKUP(A1,data1,2,FALSE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,data2,2,FALSE)),"No Match",VLOOKUP(A1,data2,2,FALSE)))
```